# Constructor threw exception;

Tags: java, spring

I'm using tomcat to run following code
but when it runs and browser opens it shows below error
I've tried to fix it but I couldn't understand what is wrong

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log org.springframework.core.log.LogDelegateFactory.getHiddenLog(java.lang.String)'
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean name="/" class="ir.maktab.HelloController"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HelloController

```
public class HelloController extends AbstractController {
    

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        return new ModelAndView("views/welcome");
    }
}
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to my web app!!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

dependencies are in maven
is it about the version of dependencies I use?

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.17.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.17.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I don't know what is wrong
please help me thank you

Comment: Could you show us the dependencies of the project gradle/maven?

Comment: Your POM file has inconsistent Spring dependencies.  A better idea is to use the BOM approach in your POM file: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38369194/139985

Answer (score 0):

You can check wheater these jars' commons-logging-1.2.jar and commons-logging-1.2-javadoc.jar are in your library or not.
You can also check your XML file from [here](https://www.roseindia.net/spring/abstractcontroller.shtml)